# Ajax in while loop

Tags: php, ajax

I'm building push notifications for my messaging system and have a weird bug.

I'm using an ajax to get recent messages. In my PHP script I have a while loop where I go through my results. So each `<li>` is a 'recent message'.

In my mind it would be simple. I put an ajax function in the `<li>` and as it iterates through the while loop it will send the values received from the iteration. Below is my PHP script.

```
$output .= "
  <li>
    <img src='$profilephoto' class='rm_pp' alt=''>
      <div class='imNotification'>
       <script>
         function getIMNotification() {
           $.ajax({
             url: 'getIMNotification.php',
             method: 'POST',
             data:{user2:'$id'},
             success:function(data) {
               $('.imNotification').html(data);
             }
           });
         }

         getIMNotification();
       </script>
     </div>
  </li>
";
```

For example, in my `getIMNotification.php` if i just echo the `user2` value sent from my AJAX, it will echo the same value for each result. But, since it's in the while loop, shouldn't it receive new values each iteration?

Is it because of the function being called? The one value being echoed is *the last* `id` in the loop. Any logic as to why it's doing that?

Comment: A function can only have one definition. If you define the function in a loop, you'll only get the last version when the function is called.

Comment: @Barmar Tru, but, he's calling it immediately, so that's hardly a problem. It might as well just not be a function.

Comment: `$('.imNotification').html(data);` of course updates ALL `.imNotification` elements, not just the one nearby the script tag.

Comment: ah i figured so..and the reason for the function in the first place was so that when they click on the image i open the chat and setTimeout(theFunction, 0) so it resets

Comment: taking the ajax out of the function doesn't fix the fact that your selector is doing exactly what it should be.

Comment: You need one ajax function, not  a whole bunch in a loop. You need an event that will use `$(this)` to act on the current element by activating only one `getIMNotification()` function. You would like feed in `this` or `$(this)` into the function.

Comment: okay i see I don't know why i didn't think about that. what if i put a hidden input with value = '$id' and call the function in the loop and below the loop have my function that makes a variable like var id =  $(this).siblings('input').val();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't redefine the function in the loop. You should define the function once, and have it take the ID as a parameter. Then you can call it separately for each `LI`.

You also need to put the result in the specific DIV for that message. `.imNotification` selects all the DIVs with that class. You can use `$id` in the ID of the DIV to target each one.

The function doesn't need to come from AJAX, you can just put this in the original HTML:

```
function getIMNotification(id, target) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'getIMNotification.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
      user2: id
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $('#' + target).html(data);
    }
  });
}
```

Then the PHP would be:

```
$output .= "
  <li>
    <img src='$profilephoto' class='rm_pp' alt=''>
      <div class='imNotification' id='imNotification-$id'>
       <script>
         getIMNotification('$id', 'imNotification-$id');
       </script>
     </div>
  </li>
";
```

Comment: yes that works perfect! so I tried something similar before i set id variable as a param and passed in the loop similar to your answer but it was setting the id and target on the div that made the selector load individually! Thank you so much for your time and explanation!